# How to print at a x y cordinate in Java

Tags: java

I thought there was a way to print at a specific location in a window but I can't seem to remember and all the searches I have tried are leading me on a wild goose chase. Regardless I am trying to print at a specific x,y cord something like this:

```
PrintAt(0,0,'1');
PrintAt(25,0,'2');
PrintAt(0,25,'3');
PrintAt(25,25,'4');
```

Where the output would look something like this:

```
1                 2




3                 4
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a Dos window? A Swing GUI? Be more specific with you question.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is the drawString() method.

An example implementation is:

```
public class XyPrinter extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawString("The string i want to print", xcoordinate, ycoordinate);
        }
}
```

Where you would add this JPanel to a JFrame or whatever you're using.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but you forgot the super.paintCompoent(g) at the start of the method.

Comment: I thought there was an easy way to do this outside of using paint but I guess not. This will work though, thank you.